# How can I move a table in Migradoc PDF Sharp to a new page

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

I am using Migradoc and PDFSharp for the first time. Currently someone has written the code where a table is created and footer is placed in the middle of the page. Then another table gets just below the footer on the same page. How can I make the footer placed exactly at the bottom of the page, and how can I move this table below the footer to the next page? Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

You add a pagebreak by calling `section.AddPageBreak()`.

To get a footer at the bottom of the page, use `section.Footers.Primary`.

See this sample:
http://www.pdfsharp.net/wiki/HelloMigraDoc-sample.ashx